# Display full log (it gets shortened with "...")

Tags: elixir

I have log written:

```
Logger.info(payload|>inspect)
```

payload comes in binary format and can be rather big.

For debugging purpose I need to it to be written fully, however, I get:

```
15:04:31.269 [info] <<10, 36, 102, 102, 100, ...>>
```

Like this, but I shortened the line to fit (is is bigger).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to provide `truncate: :infinity` option (or bite size you need)

```
config :logger, :info,
  path: Path.join('log', "#{Mix.env}.log"),
  level: :info,
  truncate: :infinity
```

Comment: What's the point of creating questions if you know the answer and answer right after sending question?

Comment: @PatNowak, it wasn't right after, I tried to google it, found nothing and then waiting for answer got the idea that this may be covered in Logger module documentation

Comment: in erlang shell you can print the whole structure using the rp/1 command: `rp(A_long_list)` or `rp(Any_expression)`

Comment: @PatNowak Answering a question while asking it is officially supported (see the "Answer your own question" checkbox in the [ask question page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)), and encouraged so long as the question isn't a duplicate. Remember, having the information here may help others searching for answers in the future.

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Your question and your answer helped me. Thanks!